# Error: 'Program.Math()' is a method, which is not valid in the given context

Tags: c#

I'm a very new beginner and I had these simple math codes working, until I started messing with methods. I don't get why Program.Math isn't working anymore.

```
static void Numbers()
{
    Console.WriteLine("4 ^ 2 = " + Math.Pow(4, 2));
    Console.WriteLine("4 ^ 1/2= " + Math.Sqrt(4));
}
```

Comment: You need to learn to create a [MCVE]. Likely it's your class name conflicting with an existing class, but since your question isn't complete, we can't say for sure.

Comment: Those lines of code wouldn't usually throw an error - any more context to this error? Any mode code to share?

Comment: Can you please send the error message here as well?!

Comment: could please post whole class and error that you are getting? The code that you post is OK by it self and shouldn't throw error.
My assumption is that your method should be public if you accessing it from another place. But it's only my assumption.

Answer (score 1):

> 'Program.Math()' is a method, which is not valid in the given context

The error above indicates that when you were *"messing with methods"*, you created a local method named `Math`, and now the compiler assumes that you are trying to call your `Math` method instead of the static class in the `System` namespace.

To resolve this, either rename your local `Math` method, or use the fully-qualified name to the class you're using:

```
static void Math()
{
    // You wrote some local method named Math which is confusing the compiler
} 

static void Numbers()
{
    // If you specify 'System.Math', now the compiler knows what you mean
    Console.WriteLine("4 ^ 2 = " + System.Math.Pow(4, 2));
    Console.WriteLine("4 ^ 1/2= " + System.Math.Sqrt(4));
}
```